# get Special Character

Tags: java

I would like to intercept the arrow keys on the java command line to move a character inside the shell!

Comment: Tell us more about why you need it and what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 2):

[JLine](http://jline.sourceforge.net/) uses native code (for Windows) to get the arrow-keys you might want to look at the source code.